# Mongo db client library in drupal 7 module without composer

Tags: php, mongodb, drupal, drupal-7, autoload

I am trying to connect to mongo from drupal using client library https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/blob/master/docs/tutorial/install-php-library.txt . 
I downloaded the source code. Now i want to use it in .module file

`myModule` directory structure inside module-

--/MongoDB (src folder of library)

--myModule.module

--myModule.info

Inside `myModule.module` file -

```
     function my_autoloader($class) {
          print_r($class);
          include DRUPAL_ROOT.'/sites/all/modules/myModule/MongoDB/' . $class . '.php';
        }

        spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');

    function myModule_init() {

    //sample code to connect to mongo
      $client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://xx.xx.xx.xx:27017");

      $collection = $client->demo->beers;

      $result = $collection->insertOne( [ 'name' => 'Hinterland', 'brewery' => 'BrewDog' ] );

      echo "Inserted with Object ID '{$result->getInsertedId()}'";
}
```

I am getting error

```
Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Client' not found
```

What i am doing wrong . any idea ???

**Note** : I am able to connect when i try to use this

```
  $m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://xx.xxx.xx.xx:27017");

  echo "Connection to database successfully";
```

but why not using client ???

Comment: got it working , had to add   $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class); and removed MongoDB from path

Comment: Then mark your question as solved please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was  `print_r($class);`  was giving output like `MongoDB\Client\` (in name space format) , 
Then all i had to do replace \ with / using

`$class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);`

and remove MongoDB from url.
Still don't know the reason why it was giving `MongoDB\Client\`